# How to change bootstrap toggle checkbox checked to true or false with a sweetalert confirmation event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a page to add permissions to users. There is a toggle button which enables / disables the user. when we click on the toggle, it should pop up a sweetlalert with confirmation? " are you sure? " and cancel. I have 2 funsctions. Enable and disable

script>

```
$(document).on('click.bs.toggle', 'div[data-toggle^=toggle]', function(e) {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]')
    var user= $(this).attr('data-user')
    if($checkbox.prop('checked') == false) {
         deleteAdmin(user)       
    } else{
         enableAdmin(user)
    }
    $checkbox.bootstrapToggle('toggle')
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

My form element:

"  <%=activeUser? "checked=\"checked\"":"" %>>

Functions:
function deleteAdmin(adminUserId)
    {

```
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "This will disable the user from Kaizen",
        type: 'warning',
        position: 'top-start',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Disable User'
        }).then((result) => {
                            document.location.href = '<%=request.getRequestURI()%>?<%=Constants.DELETE%>=1&limitToPerm=<%=limitToPerm%>&auId=' + adminUserId;
        })

}

function enableAdmin(adminUserId)
{

    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "Are you sure you want to enable this user again?",
        type: 'warning',
        position: 'top-start',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Enable User'
        }).then((result) => {
            document.location.href = '<%=request.getRequestURI()%>?<%=Constants.UPDATE%>=1&limitToPerm=<%=limitToPerm%>&auId=' + adminUserId;
        })

}
```

clicking on the Disable/Enable option toggles this flag before getting confirmation to perform the action. Also selecting 'cancel', the flag is still being updated. Is there a  way we could intercept the event before the toggle happens.
and the toggle shouldnot happen if the cancel is clicked.